# How can use custom regex in c#?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    private static void showMatch(string text, string expr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Expression: " + expr);
        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr);

        foreach (Match m in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "A Thousand Splendid Suns";

        string pattern = @"[>][@\/" - &',.\w+ -]+[<]";
        Console.WriteLine("Matching words that start with 'S': ");
        showMatch(str, pattern);      
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your existing code?

Comment: Nice code. What is it doing-wrong / not-doing-right?

Comment: @"[>][@\/" - &',.\w+ -]+[<]"   is not acceptable it gives syntax error

Comment: Your /" ends your string. You need to format these escape charakters in a nother way. I dont even know for what you need a " in it anyways. You could try this regex: `@"(S\w{0,})"`

Comment: That is because you have to escape the sting because it contains a ", so you can not excap it by using @

Comment: u can escape it with @ if you double the quote

Comment: u can escape without @ by using backslash, usually but in your string that causes more problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
   string pattern = @"[>][@\/"" - &',.\w+ -]+[<]";
```

double quote will escape for you. this line works now